# Create TensorFlow tensor from two smaller tensors using boolean mask

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I'm using TensorFlow and would like to create a 1D tensor `t1` from two smaller tensors `t2` and `t3`, where `len(t2) + len(t3) == len(t1)` and a **boolean mask which indicates how `t2` and `t3` should be combined**. The boolean mask indicates how to "splice" the two smaller tensors together.

To show what I mean - in numpy, this is fairly easy:

```
mask = np.array([True, True, False, False, True])

a2 = [1., 2., 3.]
a3 = [4., 5.]

a1 = np.zeros(5)
a1[mask] = a2  # use mask to splice smaller arrays together
a1[~mask] = a3

a1  # array([1., 2., 4., 5., 3.])
```

I've had a look around and can't seem to find any equivalent code for TensorFlow. `tf.where` seems to require all arguments to be of the same size, which isn't possible in my use case. Is there a simple and moderately efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try using `tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update`:

```
import tensorflow as tf

mask = tf.constant([True, True, False, False, True])

a2 = tf.constant([1., 2., 3.])
a3 = tf.constant([4., 5.])
a1 = tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update(tf.zeros((5,)), tf.concat([tf.where(mask),tf.where(~mask)], axis=0), tf.concat([a2, a3], axis=0))
print(a1)
# tf.Tensor([1. 2. 4. 5. 3.], shape=(5,), dtype=float32)
```

Simple explanation:

[image]